# Create DB User in Kubernetes Deployment

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, kubernetes

I need to create a SQL Server database user for my .NET Core app in order to perform migration and seed on app startup.

Here is my DB yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: inventory-mssql-depl
  labels:
    app: inventory-mssql-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: inventory-mssql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: inventory-mssql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: inventory-mssql
          image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 1433
          env:
          - name: MSSQL_PID
            value: "Express"
          - name: ACCEPT_EULA
            value: "Y"
          - name: SA_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: inventory-mssql
                key: SA_PASSWORD
          volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /var/opt/mssql/data
            name: inventory-mssqldb
      volumes:
      - name: inventory-mssqldb
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: inventory-mssql-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: inventory-mssql-clusterip-srv
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: inventory-mssql
  ports:
  - name: inventory-mssql
    protocol: TCP
    port: 1002
    targetPort: 1433
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: inventory-mssql-loadbalancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: inventory-mssql
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 1002
    targetPort: 1433
```

... here is my connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "InventoryConnStr": "Server=inventory-mssql-clusterip-srv,1002;Initial Catalog=Store_Inventory;User Id=testUser;Password=pa55w0rd!;"
}
```

And here is the SQL script I would like to run prior to first SQL Server login:

```
USE master;

CREATE LOGIN testUser WITH PASSWORD='pa55w0rd!', DEFAULT_DATABASE=master, DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'testUser')
BEGIN
    CREATE USER testUser FOR LOGIN testUser

    ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER testUser
    ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER testUser

    GRANT EXECUTE TO testUser
END;
```

... after I run SQL script on MSSQL server (creating user) and then deploy app I get exceptions:

[image]

I can run SQL script manually after database pod deployment, but I would like to have database user created automatically during the Kubernetes deployment.

Comment: Aside... for quite some time now the sa password is meant to be passed in via the `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD` environment variable, not `SA_PASSWORD`. Ref: [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server). At some point your new image builds will fail to launch containers.

Comment: Have you read the [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) documentation recently? It discusses database/script initalization and has a link to a project on Github that demonstrates how to setup `entrypoint.sh`, `configure-db.sh` and `setup.sql` files that can do this.

Comment: Do you mean to create the user in `master`? You'd normally create that in your user database(s).

Comment: what I wanted to do was to create user (so I don't have to store db SA credentials in appsettings) and let the app to use this login to create DB 'Store_Inventory' and run migrations and seed

Comment: You don't need a `USER` in `master` to do that. The creation of database.is a server/`LOGIN` level permission.